# MERN (Axios): Uncaught TypeError (data is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

I am new to MERN stack and I am trying to build a login/registration system on the stack.
When I am trying to make a post request it is throwing this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at registrationHandler (Register.jsx:47:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508:1
registrationHandler @ Register.jsx:47
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
```

My code is as follows:
[image: Register JSX]

**This is being called on Form Submit**

When I am making the same request from Postman it happens successfully:
[image: Postman Post Request]

Please any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I was importing **Axios** as
`import { axios } from 'axios'`
which should be

`import axios from 'axios'`.

Also, `history.push()` was replaced by `useNavigate('/')` in v6 of `react-router-dom`.

Lastly at line 30, it should be `data.data.token`.